# Does RxJS `share` operator really makes an Observable hot?

Tags: rxjs

The documentation of a `share` operator states that:
`As long as there is at least one Subscriber this Observable will be subscribed and emitting data. ... Because the Observable is multicasting it makes the stream hot`

I thought that `hot` observable is the one that starts emitting data without a need to be subscribed to?
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood what hot and cold observables are.

---

### Cold Observable

In RxJS an observable is cold (also known as unicasted), when there is one source per subscriber. When subscribing to a cold source, the pipeline gets recreated for each subscriber. Note the following: if your pipeline is computation heavy, then you'd be doing that computation everytime a new subscriber subscribes to that source.

[image: Cold Observable]

---

### Hot Observable

In RxJS an observable is hot (also known as multicasting), when there is one source for all subscribers. When subscribing to a hot source, the pipeline doesn't get recreated for each subscriber. Hot sources are useful for when you don't want to compute the pipeline for every subscriber. The pipeline will be computed once, and then the answer will be sent to all subscribers.

[image: Hot Observable]

---

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-a7ght4?file=index.ts) showing this in code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hot observables emit data even when no subscriber is active just like a websocket or mouse events. They are independent of subscribers.

Cold observables emit data only when subscribed to it, e.g. without subscribing to an obervable wrapping a http request, your http request will never happen.

Using share, your cold observable gets hot, as no new http request will happen but the old response will be remitted.

Comment: Close. Yes, it makes it hot while subscribed to, but `myObservable.pipe(tap(x => console.log(x)), share())` will not log anything until the first subscriber, then will stop logging when no subscribers, and will then restart the observable if anything subscribed again.

Comment: Obviously it will not log anything until you use log commands. But e.g. websockets do not care if anyone subscribes to it or not, it will still emit events.

Comment: Yes, but we are not talking about turning a hot observable into a hot observable, we are talking about turning a cold observable into a hot observable. `o$.pipe(share())` does not fool observable `o$` into thinking it was subscribed. Therefore, if `o$` is a cold observable then it will not emit anything until subscribed, will stop emitting when unsubscribed, and act exactly how you would expect if it has subscribers again.

Comment: Yes, when o$ is cold, it will not emit anything until subscribed.